# Restart Countdown Timer when expired

Tags: jquery, countdown

I'm using countdown timer from here http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html

I want if my timer is expired  it will restart. My implementation below did not restart the timer after expiration. Please help.

**HTML**

```
  <span id="divtimerholder"></span>
```

**JavaScript**

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
          startCountdown();
        function startCountdown() {
            $('#divtimerholder').countdown({ layout: '{mnn} : {snn}', timeSeparator: ':', until: 60, onExpiry: restartCountdown
            });

        }
        function restartCountdown() {
            $('#divtimerholder').destroy();
            startCountdown();
        }
    });
```

**JSFiddle**
http://jsfiddle.net/zD2M2/

Comment: The timer code is adding the "hasCountdown" class to the #divtimerholder span and I assume checks for that on init, which is why your code isn't restarting it. Impirator's answer looks like the correct way to handle it.

Comment: Looks like I clicked away from the fiddle too quickly after testing that first answer, upvoted LeGec.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set the option :

```
$('#divtimerholder').countdown('option', {until: 3});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zD2M2/1/

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the code to unmake a countdown timer should be:

```
$("#divtimerholder").countdown('destroy');
```

Comment: the timer resets to 60 seconds after expiration but it doesn't do the countdown afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#divtimerholder').countdown('option', {until: 3});
```

works like a charm. thanks for the answer LeGEC